# How to inherit a SimpleRefCount subclass for a class in ns3 (Network Simulator 3)

Tags: c++, inheritance, ns-3

In network simulator 3, I want to create a Ptr< RoutingTable > object. However, the compiler returns as such:

```
./ns3/ptr.h:457:7: error: 'class ns3::dsdv::RoutingTable' has no member named 'Unref'
    m_ptr->Unref();
```

I've searched through ns3's doxygen, and I now understand that I should inherit SimpleRefCount which provides Ref and Unref methods for the class. To help me, I've reviewed the class OutputStreamWrapper which inherits from a SimpleRefCount< OutputStreamWrapper >. I have some understanding of generic types. However, I cannot for the life of me see where the actual inheritance takes place. I cannot find the link between OutputStreamWrapper and its SimpleRefCount parent.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/output-stream-wrapper_8h_source.html):

```
27 namespace ns3 {
28 
70 class OutputStreamWrapper : public SimpleRefCount<OutputStreamWrapper>
//                             ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
//                                  right here
```

If that's what you're asking.

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to be the case. However, we've found an alternative approach to our problem already. Thank you, though!

P.S. Feeling like a big idiot at how simple it is ~_~